# sprintf float and double variable

Tags: c, avr

```
sprintf(SBuff,"Float value %0.4f ",temp_float);
USART0_TransmitString(SBuff);
```

I had also tried %f, and making the temp_float variable double (%lf).

But on Usart I always get **Float value ?** in place of the temp_float value I get question mark.

Comment: We need to see how `SBuff` gets its value and how `temp_float` is declared and assigned a value.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Agreed. I'll downvote this for being unclear and not useful until it gets revised.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz SBuff gets its value via sprintf

Comment: @JimBalter: Not possible. The value of `SBuff` is *passed* to `sprintf`. It must have a value before `sprintf` is called and `sprintf` cannot change it. (Assuming `SBuff` is a `char *`, which seems likely, but it's hard to be sure.)

Comment: char      SBuff[20];     //Sending Data to the USART

Comment: @ketan Was there a reason that the answer below didn't answer your question? If so, please leave a comment why it wasn't helpful.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You're being pedantic. The value of the buffer to which SBuff points is set by sprintf. If SBuff doesn't point to (or isn't convertible to a pointer to) a valid buffer, the OP would have quite different symptoms. (Yes, yes, I know about UB, but this is engineering, not a study of formalisms. Note the Joachim didn't have to know anything about the value of SBuff to give a correct and useful answer.)

Answer (score 4):

AVR's `sprintf()` doesn't by default implement floating point to save flash space, you need to change some compiler options to make that happen;

> If the full functionality including the floating point conversions is
>   required, the following options should be used:
>
> -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm

Full details can be found [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html).